# How can I change my view in horizontal orientation and then back to portrait?

Tags: android, orientation

I want my view to change when it has changed to horizontal orientation:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      setContentView(R.layout.chartsactivity);
    }
```

This works, but I want my layout to switch back when it is in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let the system handle the layout change you have to specify a special layout for landscape mode for the layout files you want to look different in landscape mode. This is done through a special folder for landscape layouts. Just put a layout-land folder in your resources folder. If your application is running in landscape mode, and such a folder is present the system will look for layout files in this folder first and if the layout is not found fall back to the standard layout folder.

Comment: But where in my code do I map the layout objects (say its an ImageView)? I want it to download an image from a URL when it switches into landscape. I need to be able to add some logic here...

Comment: Also how will it know which standard layout to fall back to when I go back into portrait mode, if I have more than 1 layout in my layout folder?

Comment: I placed a layout in the folder called layout-land in my resources folder. Putting my phone in landscape orientation did not switch to this layout.

Comment: if you have a layout called main_screen and your phone is in landscape mode then the system will look in the layout-land folder for a file called main_screen. After switching back the system will look in the standard folder for a file called main_screen. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources for more details

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the orientation of newConfig and use a different layout in each case? It would be much better if you let the system do it for you though.

Comment: how can I let the system do it for me?